# Можно ли сделать так,чтобы спрайт отображался поверх объекта либо исчезал со сцены на время их пересечения?

Tags: c#, unity3d, canvas, ui, 2d

Проблема состоит в том,что healthBar это UI объект (слайдер) и он перекрывает спрайт летящего самолета.

Можно ли сделать так,чтобы спрайт отображался поверх healthBar'a либо исчезал со сцены на время их пересечения?

Был бы благодарен за наводку на способ отображения healthBar'a через спрайт без использования UI :)

[image: картинка]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы посмотрите на компонент [SpriteRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-SpriteRenderer.html) то увидите там такие поля как *Sorting Layer* и *Order In Layer*. Первое отвечает за слой отрисовки, второе - за порядок внутри слоя.

Такие же поля вы можете найти на компоненте [Canvas](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-Canvas.html), который используется в UI. Меняя значения в этих полях вы можете настроить что и над чем будет располагаться (то, что рисуется позже - будет перекрывать то, что нарисовалось раньше).

Если потребуется, чтобы весь интерфейс был на одном слое, а некоторые его элементы на другом - можно добавлять дополнительные *Canvas* внутри вашего UI, ставить у них флаг *override sorting* и выставлять нужные значения.

Не забывайте добавлять к новым *Canvas* компонент [Graphic Raycaster](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-GraphicRaycaster.html), если вам требуется, чтобы компоненты UI внутри этого *Canvas* были кликабельны.

Либо можете ваш healthBar сделать с помощью SpriteRenderer, а не UI)